# Symfony route is found but not matched

Tags: php, routes, symfony

I have a mystic problem today with my Symfony application.

I created a new route which conflicted with another. I changed the order but the problem was still here.

My route is :

```
# imported and prefixed routing.yml file
my_new_route:
    path: /activation-token/{activation-token}
    defaults: { _controller: MyUserBundle:User:getLicenseeIdByActivationToken }
    methods: [GET]
```

When I'm launching the `bin/console debug:router` command, my route is registered yet :

```
$ bin/console debug:router --show-controllers | grep my_new_route

my_new_route                      GET           ANY      ANY    /api/v1/users/activation-token/{activation-token}                                                                                                   FfbEasiUserBundle:Users:getLicenseeIdByActivationToken
```

I removed then the conflicting route, just to test, and tried to use the `bin/console router:match` command to check the matching of my route. I have the following output :

```
$ bin/console router:match --method GET /api/v1/users/activation-token/a

[ERROR] None of the routes match the path "/api/v1/users/activation-token/{application-token}"
```

I admit I don't understand what's wrong in my current configuration.

If anyone has a clue, please share it :D !

EDIT : I cleared the cache ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your param to a simple camelCase one. The symfony router doesn't like hyphenated route params ;)